# Efficient Python programming for 4-core PC with threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance

I'm looking to write a script to explore the parameter space in some simulation software. Initially, I just want to run the simulation script, say, 100 times, each time incrementing one parameter.

This is to run on a machine not being used for anything else, so ideally I'd make use of all four of its cores to speed up processing.

Could anyone recommend an efficient way of doing this please?

I considered generating 100 python scripts and then queuing them in a bash script.
Alternatively, I could write a single python script to perform everything in a FOR loop. I thought I could use threading to allow 4 operations to be performed at once. IF this seems sensible, is the best implementation method to hard-code into the software to make and handle 4 threads, or is there a clever way for Python to handle CPU usage efficiently?

Many thanks,

Comment: Just FYI, the reference Python implementation has a [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) which makes it pretty much impossible to utilize multiple cores when you use the `threading` module. This isn't a problem on, let's say, the CLR or JVM because it has *real* threading. IIRC, scientific libraries like `numpy` get around this by handing it in native code for *some* use cases but for all general purposes, don't put too much trust in multi-threading in CPython.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `multiprocessing` module instead of `threading`.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

You can create multiple processes, it is up to the system to optimize CPU usage.

Comment: note: don't create more processes than the number of available hardware threads.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Not always; it depends. If one of your process spends large amounts of time in I/O, another process can sneak in to utilize the CPU to maximize throughput.

Comment: yes, but based on what he wrote I'm pretty sure it's CPU bound, with not much I/O involved.

Comment: Ok, will look into this thanks. And yes, I have no I/O, only some heavy-duty equations to solve over and over again.